# How can I make sure that the newest items added to the list variable gets placed in the top and not in the bottom when it get displayed in html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC + EF

I have a Feed xml file url that gets updated every 7 minute with items, every time a new item gets added I retrieve all the items to a list variable and then I add these varible to my database table. After that I fill a new list variable which is my ViewModel from the database table. Then I declare the ViewModel inside my view which is a .cshtml file and loop throught all of the objects and display them.

How can I make sure that the newest items get placed on the top and not in the bottom?

This is how I display the items inside my cshtml note that I use a ++number so the newest item needs to be 1 and so on.. :

```
@model Project.Viewmodel.ItemViewModel
 @{
     int number = 0;
     }
 }
 <div id="news-container">
 @foreach (var item in Model.NewsList)
            {
     <div class="grid">
     <div class="number">
                    <p class="number-data">@(++number)</p>
                </div>
                <p class="news-title">@(item.Title)</p>
                <div class="item-content">            
             <div class="imgholder">
            <img src="@item.Imageurl" />
            <p class="news-description">@(item.Description) <br />@(item.PubDate) | <a href="@item.link">Source</a></p>

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>                  
     }
  </div>
```

This is how I fill the viewmodel which I use inside the .cshtml file to iterate throught and display the items

```
    private void FillProductToModel(ItemViewModel model, News news)
    {
        var productViewModel = new NewsViewModel
        {

            Description = news.Description,
            NewsId = news.Id,
            Title = news.Title,
            link = news.Link,
            Imageurl = news.Image,
            PubDate = news.Date,
        };
        model.NewsList.Add(productViewModel);
    }
```

[image: Sorry for the paint lol :P]

Sorry for the paint lol :P

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.NewsList.OrderByDescending(n => n.PubDate)
```